# how to tell if user granted your permissions or not with FB.login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I saw a similar question, and it mentions about the change in December 2011, and that part was right

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8753085/in-facebook-login-how-do-you-see-the-permissions-that-the-user-granted

but the rest of the answer is wrong

I did notice this is part of the url though

https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?version=3&error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.#cb= ...

Comment: As far as I'm aware the user either grants you all requested permissions wholesale, or none at all. So the login either works or it doesn't. No?

Comment: @deceze, not anymore, current authentication flow support optional accept for some permissions and extended permissions have separate step which can be skipped...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You will not know which permissions the user granted to your application in `FB.login` callback. You should query `permissions` connection for `user` object:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function(response){
  if (response && response.data && response.data.length){
    var permissions = response.data.shift();
    if (permissions.email) {
      alert('User have granted `email` permission');
    }
  }
});
```

**Update:**. 
While it's not stated by Facebook that callback for `FB.login` will not include `perms` or `scope` property which was used before switch to OAuth2 this is the case! There is nothing said in current documentation about permissions passed to callback for `FB.login`, `FB.getLoginStatus` or `FB.getAuthResponse`.

There is also [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262782417099861) about this behavior which is marked as **Won't Fix**

Comment: srsly? it used to work before they changed it in december :-(

Comment: maybe addwindowlistener can catch it but I'm not sure how

Comment: can I temporarily unaccept the answer, it just seems like it should work because when you click no on the auth dialog the url that xd proxy sends back has a bunch of text about the user declining the perms so there's gotta be a way to get feedback from it...

Comment: @alexl, It may seems, but it's not. I've updated my answer to clarify some things. Feel free to accept it or not, I'm not the one to judge.

Comment: @juicy the bug is marked won't fix, however here's one reason why that doesn't quite make sense: the js-sdk fb.login sits on top of the oauth dialog. Documentation for oauth dialog http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/ specifies a redirect_uri and feedback of whether perms were accepted or not is sent as part of the url to redirect_uri. Therefore fb.login does not fully implement the oauth dialog specification.

Comment: @alexl, it may be so. File a new bug, describe what you said here, desired bahavior and see what officials say. If you do I'll subscribe to it as well!

Comment: @JuicyScripter haha there's 3!
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/262782417099861
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/352661224763701
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/277458808954942